# Keycloak - How to aggregate the policy user and group attribute

Tags: keycloak, policy, mapper

In a Keycloak realm client, I want to aggregate the "policy" attribute defined on the users and their groups.

To test this, I have a user "joe" with the attribute "policy" set to "alpha". He is member of the group "project" that have an attribute "policy" set to "beta".

I have created a client mapper like this:
[policy mapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXtdF.png).
But when I log into a client webapp with "joe", I've checked the JWT token sent by Keycloak and the "policy" field is set to "alpha".

I've noticed that if I change the "Token Claim Name" to "policies" ([policies mapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i79Wt.png)) or "fake" for example, the JWT "policies" field is set to

```
"policies": [
  "alpha",
  "beta"
]
```

I don't understand why I get this behaviour and how to fix it.